# Access JAX-RS using Flex

Tags: apache-flex, ssl, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS (Rest) web service, that only enables access through SSL.

If I try to acces it though IE feeding the according parameters, I get the correct response.

Now using Flex's HTTPService component like this:

```
<s:HTTPService id="httpsService" 
               url="https://myIp:myHTTPSPort/JAXRS/jaxrs/GetText" 
               resultFormat="text"
               result="httpsService_resultHandler(event)"
               fault="httpsService_faultHandler(event)">
   <s:request>              
      <text>My Text</text>              
   </s:request>
</s:HTTPService>
```

The fault event is started with the "HTTP request error" faultstring.

I already added this crossdomain file to the WEB-INF folder of the web service project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="flexApplicationIp" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

...but as you might have guessed didn't work.

I have a self generated HTTPS certificate on the host of my web service, so I dont'k know if I need to add it on Flex somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the "flexApplicationIp" are you putting in real IP addresses, or domains? If domain is it the fully qualified domain as it is in the cert? I run into this problem all the time on our corp network, the cert is for server.a.b.com, and in a browser we can get to it from just "server", but it does a redirect, and the service clients won't follow the redirect, and reject the cert as wrong domain.

Comment: I'm putting the real ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added the certificate following the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598687/consuming-https-webservice-in-flex-4/6225845#6225845) and voilá... Got it working

Answer (score 0):

at least, crossdomain.xml should be placed in root of your war file, because it has to be accessible by flash plugin. according to specification, contents of WEB-INF is NOT directly accessible by clients.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion...

Following it i placed the crossdomain.xml file on the WebContent folder, where META-INF and WEB-INF are contained instead of in the WEB-INF folder, but unfortunatelly that didn't work.

Any more ideas?

Comment: do you see (in the server log files) if client request ever reaches the server? another question: does it work without SSL?

Comment: Yeah the request reaches the server, and without SSL Flex sucessfully gets the results...

Comment: could it be, that you download your flashlet over http and try to connect over https?